# Simultaneous onmouseover event

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I need to have one large image with 3 images on each side. When the cursor goes over a smaller image the larger one is replaced with a larger version of the smaller image with a text description of the image underneath, but I have no clue how to do multiple events like this. I'm new to Javascript and would appreciate any help.

This is the script in the head section:

```
function changeImage(img_src,txt) {
    //change image code
    document.getElementById("preview").src = img;

    //change text code
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

The code for one of the smaller images:

```
<img width="180" height="134" src="africa.jpg" onmouseover='changeImage("africa.jpg","Exotic Wooden Animals")' />
```

And the code for the larger image:

```
<div id="description">
    <img src="Untitled-1.gif" id="preview" width="500" height="441">
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see your markup and JS? What have you tried?

Comment: This is not a multiple event. Place your javascript code that changes the large image in the `onMouseOver` event of the smaller one.